# Data returned by JSON not getting populated

Tags: jquery, json

I have an `autocomplete function` in my code for my mobile site and I am using `getJSON` to get the suggested values. `JSON call` is returning the dataset when I see in the firebug window but the `function(data)` branch is getting by-passed. The `alert("hello");` that I have coded in the branch never gets called. As a result my `suggest_box` element remains empty.

Exactly the same code is working perfectly well in my desktop site. Can someone please help me here?

```
jq("#search_store").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) 
        {
            jq.getJSON("<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . "marketplace/storesearch/autocompleteproduct"; ?>", 

            {   param: request.term, 
                seller_id : id
            }, 

            function(data)
            {
            alert("hello");
            jq(".suggest_box").html("");
                jq(".suggest_box").hide();
                var searchResultHtml = "";


                if(data.val == ""){
                    jq(".suggest_box").text('No matches found');
                    jq(".loader").css("display","none");
                }
                else{
                    jq.map(data.val,function(m){
                    searchResultHtml += suggestion_box(m);
                    jq(".suggest_box").html(searchResultHtml);
                });
                }
                 jq(".suggest_box").show();
            }
            );

        },
           search: function(event, ui) 
           {
                jq(".loader").css("display","inline-block");
            }


    });
```

Comment: What else have you done to debug the issue? Is the request sent at all? There could be multiple reasons. I suggest to add an error handler as shown in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ .

Comment: I have looked at the code using firebug and there i see that the request is being sent GET http://localhost/magentonew/marketplace/storesearch/autocompleteproduct?param=yak&seller_id=8     200 OK  549ms and the result set is also being seen in the firebug window but the div (suggest_box) is not getting populated .... let me try the error handler you have mentioned

Comment: i added error handling .fail(...) Now statusText is OK, status is 200 but why is it still entering .fail loop and not going to .done loop

Comment: yak{"val":[{"sp_flag":"1","id":"3979","has_Options":0,"weight":"Size: 500gm","name":"Yaka R","base_price":55,"special_price":50,"quantity":"<input type=text value=1 class=quantity >"},{"sp_flag":"1","id":"4150","has_Options":0,"weight":"Size: 210gm","name":"Ong's Teriyaki Sauce","base_price":250,"special_price":175,"quantity":"<input type=text value=1 class=quantity >"},{"sp_flag":"1","id":"5666","has_Options":0,"weight":"Size: 325ml","name":"Yakult Fermented Milk Drink","base_price":55,"special_price":53,"quantity":"<input type=text value=1 class=quantity >"}]}    This is my json output

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON. Where is "yak" coming from? What does the error message say?

Comment: yak is what i entered in the autocomplete field .... error message says UNDEFINED .... JSON was supposed to pull everything that had YAK in it

Comment: Well, if "yak" is prepended to the JSON then it makes the response invalid JSON. Make sure the server returns valid JSON. I mean, just copy and paste the response to http://jsonlint.com/ . *"error message says UNDEFINED"* I doubt that.

Comment: i think yak getting prepended is the problem ... if i remove yak then the JSON is valid

Comment: turned out that inside my controller i had put an echo stmt to debug and did not remove it... that was getting prepended to the json output... thx Felix